# Identical notebook cell in identical environment not working on another machine

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Identical JuypterLab notebook, or cell to be more precise, containing the same exact code executes on my PC while running like in a loop on my laptop ([*]).

PC is my primary workstation. Both the PC and laptop are 64 bit using Win10 Pro. The code in question is a plotly plot which needs these modules to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

It runs perfectly and instantly on the PC.

The exact same notebook, with the exact same environment is running indefinitely on the laptop.
The environment was copied from PC to laptop using conda: `conda install --name myenv --file spec-file.txt`.
Every other cell (which doesnt use plotly!) works fine on both machines and gives the exact same output along with similar execution timings, this goes for all the other notebooks as well. Ive tried copying the cell and copying the cell contents to another empty cell. Still runs indefinitely. Ive also tried reinstalling plotly but that also doesnt solve the problem. The notebook imports the modules with no error.

The cell in question is this one:

```
# national park names, states and coordinates
data = {
    "Location": ["Bryce Canyon, Utah", "Great Smoky Mountains, Tennessee", "Yosemite, California", "Yellowstone, Wyoming"],
    "Latitude": [37.5930, 35.6131, 37.8651, 44.4279],
    "Longitude": [-112.1871, -83.5532, -119.5383, -110.5885]
}

# make a dataframe and plot the USA map with the data as annotated dots
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# define the desired colors
colors = ["limegreen", "dodgerblue", "orange", "red"]

# generate a scatter plot on a geographical map of the USA, with customized appearance and layout settings
fig = px.scatter_geo(df, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", hover_name="Location")
fig.update_geos(visible=True, resolution=110, scope="usa", showcountries=True, countrycolor="black", showsubunits=True, subunitcolor="gray", landcolor="#f8f8f8")
fig.update_layout(autosize=True, margin={"r":0,"t":20,"l":0,"b":0})

# customize the dot colors
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=8, color=colors), selector=dict(type="scattergeo"))

# location annotation
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattergeo(
        lat=df["Latitude"] + 1,
        lon=df["Longitude"],
        text=[
            "<b>Bryce Canyon, Utah</b>",
            "<b>Great Smoky Mountains, Tennessee</b>",
            "<b>Yosemite, California</b>",
            "<b>Yellowstone, Wyoming</b>"
        ],
        mode="text",
        textposition="middle center",
        showlegend=False,
        hoverinfo="none",
        textfont=dict(size=12, color=colors),
    )
)

# title
fig.add_annotation(
    x=0.5,
    y=1.05,
    text="<b>Biodiversity in Focus: Exploring Species Endangerment and Sightings across Four American National Parks</b>",
    showarrow=False,
    font=dict(size=16, color="black", family="Calibri"),
)

# lock the layout
fig.update_layout(dragmode=False, mapbox=dict(zoom=False))

# save the figure
fig.write_image("TitleFigure1.png", scale=3)

# display the figure
fig.show()
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried trimming the code to minimal form to see what causes the blocking?  2) Exporting static images requires Kaleido. Are you sure that all dependencies are installed?  3) What do you use to run the notebooks? Browser? PyCharm? VSCode?

Comment: 1) Yes, I copied and ran the cell in another notebook. 2) I have Kaleido, but since the environment is cloned using conda, it has the same dependencies as the working one. 3) Browser on both systems.

Comment: Break up the cell, basically at each empty line, and then run them one by one to see which one blocks. You could also run it in debug mode and put breakpoints at each line.

Comment: After breaking up the cell line by line, each line runs successfully except "fig.write_image(...)" which runs indefinitely. Also, there is no graph output (there is only blank space under the cell where the graph should be rendered), the same result can be observed if the cell is ran without write image option (blank space without graph).

Comment: I finally got around to trying the code. For me it works, at least when running in VS Code: it shows a map with colored dots which is also saved as a PNG. Which exact Python version is running? The Python version itself is not necessarily controlled via the depenencies.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Exam time is in full swing. Each environment and my default Python are using the same version, Python 3.11.3 ; I've intentionally made them all use the same version to mitigate such problems (my current scope of learning allows me to use the same version for everything I do)

Comment: I found some more info. Can you find the EXACT full version number of Kaleido?

Comment: I hope this makes it easier: https://imgur.com/a/1V43MU4; The first block is self-explanatory. "Jupyterlab" and "Codecademy" are environments that, as you can see, have the same kaleido versions. I've checked; the same versions are on my PC as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downgrading the kaleido version to 0.1.0 or 0.1.0post1. To be safe you could clone the environment and then install the downgraded version.
There may be issues with the exact Windows build version, both on Win11 and Win10.

https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/110

Apparently Conda labels 0.1.0post1 as 0.1.0

```
conda install python-kaleido=0.1.0
```

or

```
pip install kaleido==0.1.0post1
```

Comment: This solves the running indefinitely part, the picture saves as a png and looks how it needs to. However, there is no picture output in the notebook (under the code cell), there is only blank space where the picture should've been.

Comment: At least half the problem solved. What happens when you specify fig.show(renderer='browser')  ?

Comment: It opens up a new tab which, after some time, says "This site can't be reached". I will try to solve this later today or tomorrow. If you have any ideas, they are most welcome. For solving the more important part of the problem, thank you!!!

Comment: Not really a good solution, more of a workaround: I've transitioned to the VSCode using their extensions for Jupyter and Python. I'm using the exact same kernels. Now everything works perfectly. Stephan thank you once again!